# Customize Mautic navigation

Tags: user-interface, customization, mautic

I have Mautic setup on my server and I want to customize the UI for navigation. What I want to achieve is that I want to add a custom navigation bar on the top of every page with an image and 3-4 links.

What is the recommended way to do this in Mautic. I want my implementation to be upgrade safe and I also want to use the best practices for such a task.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Two way to achieve this :

1. Create custom plugin and override existing navigation file and header. Which will not disturb your core files. So you can safely upgrade mautic.
   [Mautic Custom Plugin](https://www.mautic.org/blog/developer/how-to-create-a-mautic-plugin-tutorial-series-introduction/)
   [Mautic Custom Plugin Step 2](https://www.mautic.org/blog/developer/how-to-create-a-mautic-plugin-step-2/)
2. Our create custom theme and do customisation [Custom Mautic Theme](https://www.logicify.com/en/blog/how-to-create-a-custom-mautic-theme-with-your-corporate-identity-step-by-step-guide-by-logicify/)

In plugin approach. First create plugin and then override existing navigation html file.

Search for exact file first by search html code. Then you will get exact html file which you need to change and path. Then copy same file paste into plugin directly same way in CoreBundle.

Use this guide to override or inheritance.

https://symfony2-document.readthedocs.io/en/latest/cookbook/bundles/inheritance.html

Comment: Thanks for the reply. In the second approach, the solution will be limited to the custom theme only? Meaning if we switch to another theme the changes that we made will be gone, correct?

Comment: Yes. Choose first one more efficient

Comment: in the plugin approach can you please guide about where in the plugin should I make UI specific changes that I am looking to achieve

Comment: If we directly make changes to the app/bundles it will be overwritten by the upgrade, right?

Comment: Yes. its not safe not recommended.

Comment: how can I override app\bundles\CoreBundle\Views\Default\base.html.php?

I seem to be stuck

Comment: Have you created plugin as per mention in document. First lets create plugin.

Comment: plugin has been created

Comment: Please guide me on how to extend app\bundles\CoreBundle\Views\Default\base.html.php ```$view->extend('MauticCoreBundle:Default:base.html.php'); ``` does not seem to be working for me

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/201362/discussion-between-aviboy2006-and-androidharry).